# Adding images as long as there is space

Tags: javascript, height

Let's say I have two elements next to each other, one is just text of an article and next to it – ads (images). I want to create as many ads as possible to match their total height with the article's height.

I'm creating ads in an element using this function:

```js
function selectADS(adNumber, element, adsArray) {
  let usedNum = []
  let i = 0

  while (1) {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * ads.length)

    if (!usedNum.includes(randomNum)) {
      let link = document.createElement('a')
      link.setAttribute('href', ads[randomNum].bannerHref)
      link.setAttribute('target', '_blank')

      let ad = document.createElement('img')
      ad.setAttribute('alt', ads[randomNum].alt)
      ad.setAttribute('src', ads[randomNum].bannerUrl)

      element.appendChild(link)
      link.appendChild(ad)

      usedNum.push(randomNum)
      i++
      if (i == adNumber) break
    }
  }
}
```

And the function call would be like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  selectADS(8, rightSideBarAD, ads);
});
```

Ads are stored in an array of objects. For now, it creates 6 ads, or any number I want, but I need it to create as many as possible.

I tried to sum the height of every single ad in the loop and then check if it's bigger than the height of the element next to it, but it doesn't seem to work. Height of single ad always console logs `0`.

```js
h += ad.offsetHeight;
```

Height of the text element:

```js
let boxHeight = box.offsetHeight;
```

Comment: `ad.offsetHeight` will only work, if you actually appended the element to the document already at that point. If not, the browser has no objective to render it to begin with, and therefor you can't get any dimensions either.

Comment: And since these are images, it adds the complication that these need to finish _loading_ first, before the browser can determine their size. So unless you preload the images or have their sizes available in some data structure upfront where you could look them up, you will have to work with `load` event handlers on those images, to be able to check their height once they have loaded. (Which would make the whole process quite asynchronous, and increase the complexity of the overall task.)